# Symfony 5 JWT Token not found

Tags: apache, symfony, jwt

I'm using a docker image with an **apache** server and i'm trying to run a **JWT Authentication** on **Symfony 5** using the `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle`. I followed the official doc [LexikJWTAuthenticationDocs](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration) here is what I've done :

I ran the command : `php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair`
which gave me a **public** and **private** key pair. I made sure that the private key is not encrypted as I could see in this post answer : [Encrypted private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667976/401-jwt-token-not-found).

here is the configuration of the `security.yaml` :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        database:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

here is my `routes.yaml` :

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

the `lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml` :

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
#    token time to live 1 hour
    token_ttl: 3600
```

the `.env` :

```
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=test
```

with all this configuration I'm using to postman to retrieve the token from the user :

[postman get token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKfvs.png)

and with this token I'm now trying to fetch from the api every users at `api/users`

[postman get users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Anx.png)
but the response is the **401 status** and `JWT Token not found`

my apache configuration is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

This might have something to do with the apache configuration as I could see in a lot of Stack Overflow questions but i've tried a lot of them and nothing seems to work for me even this from the **LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle** :

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

**Why am I able to create a token but not use him to access data ?**

Comment: I share my answer here to resolve this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70787257/3556984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `.htaccess` or `000-default.conf` you must change the conf in : `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and add `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` at the end of the file.

However I didn't find any ressource that explain why apache remove authorization header