# Why i still have : JWT token 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource. ? using docker LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle and Apiplatform

Tags: docker, api-platform.com, docker-volume, lexikjwtauthbundle

i want to get information from my API protected by access_control, my user is logged and i still have the error "Full authentication is required to access this resource." Even when i pass my Bearer token through the header.

there is no Apache htaccess or Encrypted key like i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667976/401-jwt-token-not-found)

from the /docs interface and from my front-end, my requests are likes

[Login request successed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axcaa.png)

[Browsing users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdHl9.png)

Here is my api/config/packages/security.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\User: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/_(profiler|wdt)
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            provider: users
            jwt: ~
        main:
            json_login:
                check_path: /auth # The name in routes.yaml is enough for mapping
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS } # Allows accessing API documentations and Swagger UI docs
        - { path: ^/auth, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Here is my api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    title: Hello API Platform
    version: 1.0.0
    # Mercure integration, remove if unwanted
    mercure: ~
    formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
    docs_formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        jsonopenapi: ['application/vnd.openapi+json']
        html: ['text/html']
    # Good defaults for REST APIs
    defaults:
        stateless: true
        cache_headers:
            vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
        extra_properties:
            standard_put: true
            rfc_7807_compliant_errors: true
    event_listeners_backward_compatibility_layer: false
    keep_legacy_inflector: false
    swagger:
         api_keys:
             JWT:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
```

When i followed the tutorial i had an error at this command generating key command

[screen from error putting acl on docker volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmrcv.png)

is it possible that my error come from here ? and i didn't find how to fix it

Comment: Please post the code  and error as a text, not an image.